# Problem with clicking OK in alert python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i have problem with clicking "OK" in alert, driver switch to alert not working. I think that extension open new widow with alert.

I tried:

```
try:
    alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
    alert.accept()
except:
    pass
```

[image]

Comment: Please share what exactly have you tried so far? Without what we can not help.

Comment: This is ALL your code?

Comment: @Prophet I gave the code that I tried to click on the alert. There is no point in entering the earlier code as the code applies to the chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
try:
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
except:
    pass
```